# Opening a Modal from any page, triggered from the navbar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am wanting to put the Modal trigger button into the navbar of the _Layout.cshtml, and be able to open the modal regardless of what url I am currently on.

My modal is housed inside a folder structure of abc/forms/create

I am only able to fire the modal up when on that page, im not quite sure how to get around the issue. for example if i was on the page of abc/forms/record the modal wouldnt fire

Below is my code for the modal (I have removed all inputs and labels etc... to save space

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

nav bar below

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark py-3 mb-4 " style=" border-bottom: 3px solid #5bc0de;">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a asp-page="/Index">
                    <img src="~/assets/logo-bg.png" class="img-responsive" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="navbar-brand text-info mr-auto m-3 mr-2 " asp-area="" asp-page="/Index"><i class="fas fa-home text-success m-1"></i>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="navbar-brand text-info mr-auto m-3 mr-2" asp-area="" asp-page="/Forms/Index"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt text-warning m-1"></i>Resolution</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="navbar-brand text-info mr-auto m-3 mr-2" asp-area="" asp-page="/Forms/Records"><i class="far fa-folder-open text-danger m-1"></i>Records</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="navbar-brand text-info mr-auto m-3 mr-2" asp-area="" asp-page="/Forms/Create"><i class="far fa-folder-open text-danger m-1"></i>Create</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <form class="form-inline">
                    @*<a  class="btn btn-info form-control text-white d-inline-block m-3" style="width: 150px; ">Create Record</a>-->*@
                    <a asp-page="/Forms/Create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                        Create
                    </a>
                </form>
                @*<Partial name="_PartialButton" />*@
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: You have to put the modal code in  your `_Layout.cshtml` also, otherwise how would expect it to fire?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am new to Asp, how would i be able to access my model properties inside the _Layout for example <input asp-for="item.Forename">/>

Comment: Use a partial: `<Partial name="/Forms/Create" model="new MyModel()" />` in your layout for example.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Partial View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#partial-tag-helper) in Asp.net core. Below is a simple demo.

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Create
</button>

<partial name="_ModalPartial.cshtml" model="new User()"  />
```

__ModalPartial.cshtml:

```
@model User

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label asp-for="Forename"></label>
                <input asp-for="Forename" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey mj thank you. I have a quick question. I have dropdown menus inside my modal which pull their data from different models, they are being used as look up tables. How can I send data from two different models to the partial view tag helper inside _layout. I am using new SelectList() for the dropdown

Comment: Hi @Rowandinho, if the modal has data to fill, I would suggest use ajax to load the partial view instead of using the `partial` tag.